# My radiator fan keeps on right after shutting off the car (Hyundai Accent 2002 GL 1.6)

Tags: coolant, radiator, hyundai, sensor, accent

My car radiator fan keeps on working right after shutting down my car, which is strange and never happened before. I suspected the temperature sensor, but through the OBD II kit, I am able to read around 85 degrees variating which is definitely normal, and no fault code. Do you have any idea what it can be?

The vehicle is a Hyundai Accent 2002 GL 1.6.

Comment: Do you mean the fan stays on? Does it shut down after some time? You could check your radiator fluid (level, consistency etc) as it perhaps isn't cooling as efficiently as it used to.

Answer (score 2):

This is normal behavior for some vehicles. They utilize the fan to further cool the system after engine shut down (even though it does not further circulate the coolant). This is something I would not be worried about.

Comment: But as you say when the engine is shut the water pump doesn't circulate any coolant so what is the purpose? and this behavior started over 2 weeks so honestly I don't think it is normal.

Comment: The idea behind this is to control the 'heat rise' of the engine coolant when you switch off the engine. You can see the heat rise if you stop the engine after a run, then switch the ignition on again without starting the engine. Watch the temp gauge reading rise up. The fans running minimise this heat rise.